# Restoring VIM to default state

Tags: vim, ubuntu-11.04

I'm really frustrated with getting going using VIM. I'm just trying to do some minor customizations to the vimrc file. I made some minor changes, but they didn't do what I had hoped. So, I went back in and removed the lines that I had added, reverting back to my original file. Now, I can't even get into VIM! When I type "vim filename.xxx" from the terminal, I just go right back to a command prompt. No error message, no file opens, nothing. It's as if I just hit the enter key.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VIM, but same results. Does anyone know what I can do to get VIM back to its original state? I'm using Ubuntu 11.

Comment: Did you put your configuration in `~/.vimrc` or in `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try removing the ~/.vimrc and ~/.viminfo files and the ~/.vim directory. These usually contain configuration information so getting rid of them should give you a fresh start

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest first uninstalling but purging, reinstalling, and making sure your local user edits are removed.

- Purge to remove the package config files: `sudo apt-get purge vim`.
- Clean out any personalizations: `rm -Rf ~/.vim ~/.vimrc ~/.viminfo`.
- Reinstall Vim again: `sudo apt-get install vim`.

Comment: Overkill or not, it got me back into vim. Thanks!